# Different startup forms for different developers using SVN in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, svn

My scenario is such that I have a VB.NET project in SVN and I am using the Application Framework to start the application. This poses a great problem when different developers are working on different forms and they want to have different startup forms.

Right now if we change the project settings, its changed for everyone else too. How can we work around this? Can SVN have a class committed into the repository and later changes cannot be committed into it? (more like ignoring a file but with a initial copy in the repo)

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an extra entry point which can show different forms based on a command line argument. (It could be as simple as finding the specified type by reflection and calling the entry point. Or a switch statement...) I'm pretty sure that the command line arguments used for debugging end up in the ".user" version of the project file (because they're designed to be per-user settings). Just make sure you don't put the .user files into svn!

Comment: This worked fine for me. Though its a constraint if the real application allows commandlines, (which is not the current situation) this is a good acceptable solution

Comment: If the real application had multiple entry points, you'd still need some way of letting the user tell you which one they wanted to run :)

Answer (score 1):

The startup project is AFAIK stored in the *.suo file. Just don't have that file versioned - it contains user settings anyway and shouldn't be versioned.

Comment: That's saying which *project* to start though - this situation is a single project with multiple entry points, which isn't the same thing.